# Label curves with corresponding parameter

Tags: equation-solving, legending, parametric-functions, labeling

How can `Plotlegend` label each curve with the corresponding value of parameter `param` in the code below?

```
  s = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == x[t], x[0] == param, 
    y[0] == param}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}, {param}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 70, PrecisionGoal -> 20];
Plot[Evaluate[Table[x[param][t] /. s, {param, 1, 10}]], {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Comment: If you want to use `PlotLegends` use `Plot[Evaluate[Table[x[param][t] /. s, {param, 10, 1, -1}]], {t, 0, 1},
  PlotLegends -> Range[10, 1, -1]]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the option [`PlotLabels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabels.html):

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[x[param][t] /. s, {param, 1, 10}]], {t, 0, 1},
   PlotLabels -> Range[10]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`Callout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html) wrapper on each table element:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Callout[x[param][t] /. s, param], {param, 1, 10}]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

> same picture

You can also use [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) as follows:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Labeled[x[param][t] /. s,param], {param, 1, 10}]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Or add the labels using [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html):

```
Plot[Evaluate[ Table[x[param][t] /. s, {param, 1, 10}]], {t, 0, 1}, 
 Epilog -> MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], Offset[{10, 0}, {1, #}]] &, 
   Table[x[param][1] /. s, {param, 1, 10}]], 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

> almost same picture

Comment: Unfortunately in Mathematica 10.0 I get a  `Plot::optx: Unknown option PlotLabels->{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} in <<1>>. >>` error (`PlotLabels` in red).

Comment: @student, `PlotLabels` should work in versions 10.4 and later. Does `Labeled` work in your version?

Comment: @student, `Epilog` method should work in versions 9+.